# Ember js - Jquery hover effects stop working after element is hidden and redisplayed by ember {{/if}} conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I want my jquery function to still work even after the element with the function is hidden and reshown using {{#if}} conditionals.

Below is the function that ceases to work.

```
App.RecordCategoriesView = Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
    $(".isPublic").on( 'mouseover', function(){
      $(this).attr({src: "images/makePublic-blue.png"});
    });
    $(".isPublic").on( 'mouseout',function(){
      $(this).attr({src: "images/makePublic-grey.png"});
    });

    $(".isPrivate").on( 'mouseover', function(){
      $(this).attr({src: "images/makePrivate-blue.png"});
    });
    $(".isPrivate").on( 'mouseout', function(){
      $(this).attr({src: "images/makePrivate-grey.png"});
    });
      Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this._childViewsRendered);
    }, 

  _childViewsRendered: function() {
    // here your child views is in the rendered state
  },
})
```

If these images are toggled with isPublic, the hover effects of two images defined in the views ceases to work.

```
    {{#if isPublic}}
    <a class="tooltipping float-right">
      <span>Shown to Public</span>
      <img class="table-img isPublic float-right" {{action "makePrivate" this bubbles=false}} src="images/makePublic-grey.png" />
    </a>
    {{else}}
      <a class="tooltipping float-right">
        <span>Hidden from Public</span>
        <img class="table-img isPrivate float-right" {{action "makePublic" this bubbles=false}} src="images/makePrivate-grey.png" />
      </a>
    {{/if}}
```

Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Comment: change how you're binding the events, use 'on', 'on' binds to the elements that are currently in the DOM, but it also binds to the ones that are inserted in real time. The thing is that 'if' statements do not add a class to hide html code, if you check the html code, when the 'else' is executed, the html code disappears.

Comment: Hmm i've heard of this working before but it's not on mine. I've also updated the question using on().

Comment: take a look here https://api.jquery.com/live/ 'live' is deprecated, but they give you what you need to make it work with your jquery version

Comment: The same problem occurs, only this time, if the whole page reloads, none of the jquery works

Comment: This is slightly off topic from the solution you're looking for as it drops the use of jquery but if you want to fix this the ember way you should use `<img {{bind-attr src=imageUrl}}></img>` to bind a controller property to `src` and then listen for the `mouseEnter`, `mouseLeave` events in the view.  Have the view send an action to the controller which can change the bound property for you.  If you're interested in that solution I can provide a more detailed example.

Comment: It's not off topic at all. If you post the answer with more code examples on the code i could use to switch the src image, I could give you the Green Checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDidInsertElement` hook only fires when the view element is inserted (the topmost element). When an if expression is re-rendered, it's not fired. And in your case, the elements in the if block are deleted from the DOM and re-added to it when necessary. So the reason it's not working after being re-displayed is because the current DOM element is no longer the DOM element that you called the jQuery function on.

There's several workarounds, but what I would do is have the `didInsertElement` function observe the `isPublic` property. Also, make sure to use `Em.run.later` to ensure the DOM elements actually exist and are ready when the function runs. I use the code below in my codebase:

```
jqueryEvents: function() {
    Em.run.later(function() {
        this.$('.isPublic').on('mouseover', function() { ... });
    }.bind(this));
}.on('didInsertElement').observes('isPublic')
```

Comment: This response was very informative! Am I wrapping each of my hover functions in both jqueryEvents and Em.run.later, and then the entire set of functions are wrapped into the DidInsertElement?

Comment: You don't need a `didInsertElement` function. The `on('didInsertElement')` will make sure that `jqueryEvents` runs whenever the `didInsertElement` event is fired.

Comment: I ended up using Sarus' Ember conditionals method to solve my problem but he only wrote it as a comment and not an 'answer'. Your explanation helped me understand what's going on in the DOM. It's shame that the more and more I use Ember, the more I see how flawed it is like how it doesn't play nice with certain JQuery and how it neglects some key elements of a creating a large-scale app like a simple filter search bar. Anyway your response gets the green check. Thanks!

Comment: Ember isn't perfect, but it really is a very nice framework with a lot of features. Unfortunately, the learning curve is **very** steep. It takes a long time to understand why things work the way they do; but when you do understand, using Ember becomes really easy. And often, the reason behind odd decisions (like some of the awkward rendering) is due to performance. Bottom line: you'll get the hang of it eventually. Keep asking here if you need help (like with the filter search bar).

Comment: Yes, the ember conditionals are handy, even if they dont have an elsif statement. If you're looking to make an easy +50 rep, I'm trying to make this filter bar example work with my project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720183/emberjs-connecting-an-input-filter-bar-with-my-list-of-objects-as-i-typ

Answer (score 2):

Try to attach the handlers above the `{{if}}` blocks, at the level of the view element itself.

```js
App.RecordCategoriesView = Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().on("mouseover", ".isPublic", function () {
      $(this).attr({src: "images/makePublic-blue.png"});
    });
    //...
```

Comment: How would that look in HTML?

Comment: The same as it looks now. You just remove handler from the element itself, so you don't have to keep adding / removing it every time you change the DOM. Of course, you'll have to change `$(this).attr(...)` to shoot for the element that's actually under the mouse. Look [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough jujubes to comment above, but here is panta82's answer expanded and in coffeescript (for those looking for the same answer, but in coffeescript like I was)

```
RecordCategoriesView = Ember.View.extend
    didInsertElement: ->
        @$().on "mouseover", ".isPublic", ->
            $(".isPublic").attr "src", "images/makePublic-blue.png"

        @$().on "mouseout", ".isPublic", ->
            $(".isPublic").attr "src", "images/makePublic-grey.png"

        @$().on "mouseover", ".isPrivate", ->
            $(".isPrivate").attr "src", "images/makePrivate-blue.png"

        @$().on "mouseout", ".isPrivate", ->
            $(".isPrivate").attr "src", "images/makePrivate-grey.png"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; thank you for taking the time to post your code!