# Emberjs - Connecting an {{ input }} filter bar with my list of Objects. As I type, the list filters

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, filtering, handlebars.js

I am trying to incorporate this *working* example http://jsbin.com/AViZATE/37/edit of a filtering search bar with my own project. The search bar does not seem to be connected to my list of objects. :(

Let me show you what I've done.

```
App.RecordCategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchResult: function(){
        var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm');
        var regExp = new RegExp(searchTerm,'i');
        this.get('model').set('content',this.store.filter('recordCategory',function(item){
            return regExp.test(item.get('categoryName'));
        }));
    }.observes('searchTerm'),
});
```

As you can see above, I've replaced '`todo`' with '`recordCategory`' and '`title`' with '`categoryName`'. Seems good so far.'

In record_categories.hbs i've created the input bar that will be used to filter.

```
{{input type="text" id="search-todo" placeholder="Search Todo List..." value=searchTerm}}
```

and then below it, the #each handlebars to loop through and display my list

```
{{#each itemController="recordCategory"}}
  <li>{{categoryName}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Am I missing something? I noticed that searchResults doesn't seem to be called anywhere else in their example

Also here is my route because why not.

```
App.RecordCategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({     
    model: function() {
        VpcYeoman.RecordCategories.FIXTURES=[];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/recordCategories',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"get",      
            async: false,
            success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) { 
                if(xhr.status==200){
                    VpcYeoman.RecordCategories.FIXTURES=data;
                }
            }
        });
        return this.store.find('recordCategories');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to try to mostly ignore the JSBin and look at what you have, as I think that will help you more. So if I miss something obvious from the JSBin, let me know.

First thing to notice is that, from your route, you return an array of objects. Ember would normally generate an `ArrayController` for you, but you've extended that yourself. And the thing that's special (and nice) about `ArrayController`s is that their content *is* the array. So in your template, you could just do this:

```
{{#each}}
    {{categoryName}}
{{/each}}
```

And that would list all of the items that were returned from `this.store.find('recordCategories')`.

But you want to filter your items, so that's no good. So let's move on to point two. The best way to filter a list of items is by using a read-only computed property. You definitely don't want to set the content of the model to the filtered items. You want the original items to remain intact, and the filter be just a certain way of looking at the original items. So, using a slightly modified example from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/), let's do that.

```
App.RecordCategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    searchResults: function() {
        var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm');
        var regExp = new RegExp(searchTerm,'i');

        // We use `this.filter` because the contents of `this` is an array of objects
        var filteredResults = this.filter(function(category) {
            return regExp.test(category.get('categoryName'));
        });

        return filteredResults;
    }.property('@each.categoryName', 'searchTerm')

});
```

So now you've got a computed property that filters the items in the array controller based on the search term. And because of its dependancies, it will re-caclulate anytime the items change or the search term changes. And this way, you didn't have to change any model values. Finally, you'd use it like this:

```
// record_categories.hbs

{{input type="text" id="search-todo" placeholder="Search Todo List..." value=searchTerm}}

{{#each searchResults}}
    {{categoryName}}
{{/each}}
```

And just to make sure that I wasn't completely BSing, I created a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mafawusi/2/edit?html,js,output) to show that it works.

Comment: That was one of the easiest answers to follow. I had my search bar set up within minutes of reading through this. You win 50 rep points! "Need a developer? Why not Zoidberg."

Comment: Just glad I could help. I remember my frustrations when I was first starting Ember.js, so I try to help others avoid the same ones. :)

Comment: In your example of searchResults:, you use 'category' Ex. (category.get('categoryName')); instead of what i originally used (item). Is 'category' just a variable that you chose because I refer to it everywhere else as 'recordCategory'? It works for recordCategories but I ask this because I'm trying to implement this logic with a different but very similar page called 'workfloweditor'. I change 'category' to 'workfloweditor' but I get Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'filter'

Comment: `category` is indeed just a variable. It can be whatever you want. But that isn't your problem. You call `filter` on `this`. So if `filter` doesn't exist, it's likely that you have an `ObjectController` and not an `ArrayController`.

Comment: You are correct in that it was in an ObjectController. I had placed it there because the list 'workflows' exists in the 'recordCategory/#' route because every recordCategory hasMany workflows. I suppose that the search filter should be placed in 'WorkfloweditorsController' regardless of where it is located.

Comment: Tell me if you're not receiving the bounty.