# How to create a listener for dynamically created elements with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to ember and I'm not sure how to create a listener for a dynamic element.

I want to do something similar to this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.order_here', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do some actions
});
```

Comment: do you want to listen a click event on a button, or a property change on an Ember.Object

Comment: click event on a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template:

```
<div {{action "orderClicked" }}> Order </div>
```

In your controller:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    orderClicked: function() {
      // handle here.
    }
}
```

Also check out [emberjs guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/).

Answer (score 0):

Ember CLI and coffeescript

In your template:

```
<button class="order_here" {{action "OrderHere"}} >Order Here</button>
```

In your controller:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

YourController = Ember.Controller.Extend
    actions:
        OrderHere: ->
            # perform some action

`export default YourController`
```

The above is the recommended way of dealing with actions ([ember actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/)) in Ember.  However, if you are dealing with elements that are being inserted and removed from the DOM (e.g., {{#if ...}} {{/if}}) AND you need to target them with jQuery (there are a few use cases), then the following works:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

YourView = Ember.View.extend
    didInsertElement: ->
        @$().on 'click', '.order_here', ->
            console.log $('.order_here')
            # do some stuff

`export default YourView`
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592420/3993820)